# Are all cookies passed in an HTTP request?

Tags: http, cookies

I am having trouble understanding how a session is restored via cookies. How do the client know which sessionID cookie to send to the server via the HTTP request the first time? Does the client send all cookies and the server accepts the one that it also knows?

For example, let's say there are websites A and B (both using PHP), and I logged into both websites and then closed my browser. Now I open the browser again and go to site A and see that I am kept logged in. In this scenario, when my browser sends the HTTP request, the cookie whose file name contains the session ID for site A must have been included in the header. However I have two sessionID cookies for both site A and B. As far as I understand, the host name is usually not stored in the cookie, at least in many PHP tutorials of the setcookie() function. How do my browser know which sessionID cookie is for site A? Does the browser just send all cookies to A and let A figure out which is the right one by comparing all the received session IDs with stored session IDs? This does not sound right to me.